# Covariance matrix of multivariate multiple regression coefficients

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, multivariate-analysis, covariance-matrix

I would like to perform a regression analysis on a dataset comprising one independent variable (X) and two dependent variables (Y1 and Y2) which may be affected by correlated errors. R's stats::lm function handles this situation nicely, producing a 4x4 covariance matrix of the regression parameters (slopes and intercepts). I noticed that the correlation coefficient of the intercepts equals the correlation coefficient of the residuals. Is this true for all other fitting models, including Generalised Linear Models? Am I correct in thinking that:

1. The regression coefficients for the dependent variable may be obtained by fitting each of them separately?
2. The covariance/correlation matrix of the intercepts may always be obtained from the residuals?

Edit:

Here's an example:

```
library(MASS)

a1 <- 5  # intercept 1
a2 <- 10 # intercept 2
b1 <- 1  # slope 1
b2 <- 2  # slope 2
x <- 1:10 # independent variable
e <- mvrnorm(n=length(x),mu=c(0,0),Sigma=matrix(c(1,0.5,0.5,1),nrow=2)) # residuals

# generating some synthetic data:
y1 <- a1 + b1 * x + e[,1] # dependent variable 1
y2 <- a2 + b2 * x + e[,2] # dependent variable 2
y <- cbind(y1,y2)

# linear regression
fit <- lm(y ~ x)
```

Which produces the following output:

```
> fit

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
             y1     y2   
(Intercept)  4.603  9.591
x            1.095  2.066

> vcov(fit)
               y1:(Intercept)         y1:x y2:(Intercept)         y2:x
    y1:(Intercept)     0.39622492 -0.056603560     0.35146659 -0.050209513
    y1:x              -0.05660356  0.010291556    -0.05020951  0.009129002
    y2:(Intercept)     0.35146659 -0.050209513     0.44698258 -0.063854654
    y2:x              -0.05020951  0.009129002    -0.06385465  0.011609937
```

You can see that `stats::lm` has correctly retrieved both the regression coefficients and the covariance matrix of the regression coefficients. However, `stats::glm` does not accept multiple dependent variables. So I was wondering if I could calculate their covariance structure from the residuals as well.

Comment: The answer to #1 is yes. The #2 is much more interesting (and I don't know the answer).

Comment: I don't follow this. What "4x4 covariance matrix" are you referring to, eg? Is that from the `vcov()`? What do you mean that the "correlation coefficient of the intercepts equals the correlation coefficient of the residuals"? Can you paste in your code & output, or otherwise clarify what you are referring to?

Comment: @amoeba, I wouldn't necessarily say that #1 is appropriate.

Comment: @gung I have added an example to my post.